# Take a screen shot and copy through FileUtils in Selenium WebDriver and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, fileutils

When I try to get screen shots with following code it is showing error.

```
FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("*./Screenshots/facebook.png"));
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amDGJ.png)

but when i try the following code it is okay.

```
FileHandler.copy(source,new File("*./Screenshots/facebook.png"));
```

Why is that?

full code is below

```
package sample.code;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ScreenShot {

  @Test
  public void facebookScreenShot() throws IOException {

    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_m']")).sendKeys("screenshot");

    TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)driver;

    File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);    
    FileHandler.copy(source,new File("*./Screenshots/facebook.png"));

    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: it is showing "FileUtils cannot be resolved"

Comment: then import FileUtils, it's an apache commons library if not mistaken so you need to download the jar if not yet in your workspace

Comment: Ah..i checked. It is not in my workspace. I'll download and try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Robot class ,you can take screenshot.Following is the code to take screenshot.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class CaptureScreenshot {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException, HeadlessException, AWTException
    {
        // This code will capture screenshot of current screen      
        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        // This will store screenshot on Specific location
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\Screenshot\\CurrentScreenshot.png")); 

    }
}
```